# react-native AES Encryption matching Java Decryption algorithm

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, react-native, aes

The Full code of my Java Encryption/Decryption algorithm:

```
public class AESEncryptUtil {

    private static AESEncryptUtil instance = new AESEncryptUtil();
    private String password = "123456";
    private Key key;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public AESEncryptUtil(){
        try {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(password.getBytes()));
            SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
            key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static byte[] encrypt(String content) throws Exception {
        byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");
        instance.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, instance.key);
        byte[] result = instance.cipher.doFinal(byteContent);
        return result;
    }
    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] content) throws Exception {
        instance.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, instance.key);
        byte[] result = instance.cipher.doFinal(content);
        return result;
    }
    public static String parseByte2HexStr(byte buf[]) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            sb.append(hex.toUpperCase());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static byte[] parseHexStr2Byte(String hexStr) {
        if (hexStr.length() < 1)
            return null;
        byte[] result = new byte[hexStr.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hexStr.length() / 2; i++) {
            int high = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 1), 16);
            int low = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i * 2 + 1, i * 2 + 2),
                    16);
            result[i] = (byte) (high * 16 + low);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static String getNonce() {
        String base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(base.length());
            sb.append(base.charAt(number));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String content = "test";  
        System.out.println("content: " + content);  
        byte[] encryptResult = encrypt(content);  
        String encryptResultStr = parseByte2HexStr(encryptResult);  
        System.out.println("encryptResultStr: " + encryptResultStr);  
        byte[] decryptFrom = parseHexStr2Byte(encryptResultStr);  
        byte[] decryptResult = decrypt(decryptFrom);  
        System.out.println("decryptResult: " + new String(decryptResult));  
    }
}
```

I've tried many times and many ways to match the Java algorithm, but the result are always different. Which module should I use to do this ? Can anyone help me to deal it ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the right way to match two algorithm:

Java part:

```
public static String encrypt() throws Exception {
        try {
            String data = "123456";
            String key = "1234567812345678";
            String iv = "1234567812345678";

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

            byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes();
            int plaintextLength = dataBytes.length;
            if (plaintextLength % blockSize != 0) {
                plaintextLength = plaintextLength + (blockSize - (plaintextLength % blockSize));
            }

            byte[] plaintext = new byte[plaintextLength];
            System.arraycopy(dataBytes, 0, plaintext, 0, dataBytes.length);

            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String desEncrypt() throws Exception {
        String encrypted = encrypt() ;
        try
        {
            String data = encrypted ;
            String key = "1234567812345678";
            String iv = "1234567812345678";

            byte[] encrypted1 = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(data);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted1);
            String originalString = new String(original);
            return originalString;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

React native part:

pre coding: `npm install crypto-js`

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js' ;
encryptFun() {
    var data = "123456";
    var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('1234567812345678');
    var iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('1234567812345678');  
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      data,
      key,
      {iv:iv,mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding:CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    });
    console.log('encrypted: ' + encrypted) ;
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,key,{iv:iv,padding:CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding});
    console.log('decrypted: '+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
  }
```

the result :

```
encrypted: aK7+UX24ttBgfTnAndz9aQ==
decrypted: 123456
```

I hope my code would help someone:)